# Recover User account in virtual machine (after trying to extend memory)

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, partitioning, virtualbox, users

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in virtual box. 
Now the desktop doesn't appear after I log in with my username.

I can still log in with the guest account. I think this is the result from an unsuccessfull memory extension of the virtual machine (the memory was fixed, but I didn't realise this until after) or from trying to update to Ubuntu 16.04. without having enough disk space.

Is there any way to retrieve the files on my user account?

Comment: Adding memory (to a real machine or to a virtual machine) should not produce the symptoms you describe. I therefore suspect that something else is going on -- most likely damage to files in the user's home directory or to the account configuration. You might try using an emergency disk to boot the VM and create a fresh (empty) home directory or create a new user account. I don't know of any step-by-step instructions for doing this, though, and it's just complex enough that I don't have time to verify a procedure. Maybe you'll be able to find something through a Web search, though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no attempt to rescue your broken installation (we don't know what went wrong) but to show you how to recover files from your HOME when the virtual OS won't boot.

#### Create a new virtual machine

You may want to recreate a running virtual machine anyway - so it is the best time to do that now. Please also create a new virtual disk (VDI) file for your new installation an make it large enough to not run out of space again. When creating a dynamically growing disk it will not use up more physical space than needed but it can grow up to the size we gave it on demand. So it is safe to create a large virtual drive (tak 50 or 100 GByte if your system allows this).

#### Bind the old virtual disk to your new virtual machine

If all is set up to your liking you may want to copy your personal files from the broken virtual machine. To do so you just add the old VDI-file that holds your broken Ubuntu:

[image]

You will see that you new Ubuntu is able to mount this drive with Nautilus. Then you can browse files and copy them over to your new machine. As long as you don't delete the old VDI you have all the time you need to do so.

When all is finished you can remove the old drive from the virtual machine.

Comment: This worked! I inserted the old vdi drive and an Ubuntu 14 ISO. When creating the Virtual Machine I had to choose "no hard drive" so Ubuntu would not boot the old vdi file when starting the virtual machine. Then I clicked on TryUbuntu and was able to view and retrieve my old files!