# Copying files from my /home in a rescue boot shell on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, login

I have a Mac with a Ubuntu 14.04 installed in VirtualBox.

During an update I lost my login window. Someone suggested I should uninstall and reinstall guest additions but that sounds like too much hassle. I just want to log in and move the files I want to my shared folder and then delete the whole thing and start over.

When I hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> button I get the the GRUB menu and I can choose recovery mode. Now I'm in a shell "root@ virtualbox" but I can't get anywhere.

`ls` command does nothing. I don't even know where I am.

How do I find my user's home folder and move the files?

I also tried to mount the vdi image but its not working:

http://bluepilltech.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image-under.html
https://unfinishedbitness.info/2017/02/06/mac-os-x-native-vdi-image-mounts/

Installing a new ubuntu in the VBox has worked great. Thank you! I can look at the old vdi just fine but the home folder is still encrypted. So I am wondering if I change the root password in the encrypted machine will it use the newly made pw to encrypt and therefore I can see the contents of the home folder again?

Comment: Boot the VM from the installation ISO and in the live session mount your virtual hard disk somewhere, the manipulate the files using the normal tools.

Comment: sorry wrong thread

Comment: thank you sounds good. You have a link on how to do this?

Comment: Your [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/981204/revisions) is completely understandable but it is confusing anyway in its current context because you are asking a different question in the last paragraph while everything from the original revision still remains there in the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the prompt do:

```
 cd /home
 ls
```

what do you see? Also:

```
 lsblk
```

and

```
 fdisk -l
```

This should give you similar listings of available block devices and their partitions. Does any of those partitions look like your /home partition?

The ones that are interesting are listed as "Type Linux" or similar in the `fdisk` listing. F.ex., let's assume there is a /dev/sda1. Now what you can do is to mount that partition somewhere:

```
 mkdir test_dir
 mount /dev/sda1 test_dir
 ls test_dir
```

do not forget to unmount test_dir after you've rescued whatever you need to rescue:

```
 umount test_dir
```

Comment: thank you! I found my home folder but when I go inside and do "ls" I get: access-your-private-data.desktop  README.txt

Comment: What did you expect to be in your `/home` folder? Is it maybe encrypted? What's in the `README.txt`? `cat README.txt`

Comment: yes it looks like it. Inside the file it says: This directory has been unmounted to protect your data. FROm the command line run: ecryptfs-mount-private  and I get: ERROR: encrypted private directory  is not setup properly

Comment: So next is the task to google how to decrypt that directory manually :-)

Comment: 'encrypt-unwrap-passphrase home' is asking me for passphrase which I don't remember...I guess Ill try mounting with a live cd..

Comment: mounting with a live cd will not help you remember the pass phrase. You will need that pass phrase in any case I guess.

Comment: guess I'm up shit's creek without a paddle..I don't remember setting up a passphrase and my users password don't work. I kinda remember just using my users password for that. How about reinstalling guest additions, will that get me where I want to go?

Comment: tried running recovery graphical interface but it won't mount either: /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: no such device mountain: mount /media/mountspa (482) terminated with status 1

Comment: thank you very much. Just saw this link up there. https://askubuntu.com/questions/895334/recover-user-account-in-virtual-machine-after-trying-to-extend-memory seems like the way to go. Working on it right now.